# Last class on last headline?

Tags: php, css, loop

I have the following code which should add a last class to the fourth post but doesn't appear to be, what is wrong with this coding? It show's 4 posts fine but the fourth one doesn't have the class last attached to it.

```
      <div class="headline-strip">
        <ul>
          <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $count = 1;
  if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; ?>
          <li <?php if ($count == 4) : ?>class="last"<?php endif; ?>><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><span>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( array (176,176) );?>
            </span>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a></li>
          <?php endwhile; $count++; endif; ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$count = 1;` is set in the while loop, so every time the loop runs it sets to 1 again. Place it before your loop and it will work.

```
$count = 1; if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Ow and the $count++ is outside the loop so it will only run after all the posts.
Change that to:

```
<?php $count++; endwhile; endif; ?>
```